# No output from 8086 program when running ml program.asm in DOSBox

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-16, masm, dosbox

I got this code from the [Geeks-for-Geeks site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/8086-program-to-convert-a-16-bit-decimal-number-to-octal/), but there were lots of indentation errors, I changed the code to the following but, when running the code using MASM and DOSBox it's giving no output.

The Output I should get, According to the site I should get 20 but I get nothing, the code is saved as pro.asm, and I'm using DOSBox version 0.74.
For getting the o/p in the DOSBox I did,

```
mount c c:\8086
c:
ml pro.asm
```

Code:

```
;8086 program to convert a 16-bit decimal number to octal 

.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 100H 
.DATA 
d1 dw 16 
.CODE 
        MAIN PROC FAR 
        MOV ax,@DATA
        MOV ds,ax

;load the value stored in variable d1 
        MOV ax, d1

;convert the value to octal
;print the value 
        CALL PRINT
 
;interrupt to exit
        MOV AH,4CH 
        INT 21H 

        MAIN ENDP 
        PRINT PROC 

;initialize count   
        MOV cx,0 
        MOV dx,0 

label1:          ;if ax is zero 
        cmp ax,0
        je print1 

;initialize bx to 8
        mov bx, 8 
  
;divide it by 8 to convert it to octal 
        div bx  

;push it in the stack   
        push dx 

;increment the count
        inc cx 

;set dx to 0 
        xor dx,dx 
        jmp label1 

print1:            ;check if count is greater than zero 
        cmp cx,0 
        je exit

;pop the top of stack 
        pop dx 

;add 48 so that it 
;represents the ASCII 
;value of digits 
        add dx,48 

;interrupt to print a 
;character 
       mov ah,02h 
       int 21h 

;decrease the count 
       dec cx
       jmp print1
 
exit :  ret 
        PRINT ENDP 
        END MAIN
```

The output I'm getting can be seen below [image: output]

Comment: Well, deriving from your output, you do not execute the program `pro.exe` - you only assemble it.

Comment: @zx485: I think the code is correct. The loop that pushes to the stack increments `cx` and the code that pops loops for `cx` times.

Comment: If i want to take input from user what change will i have to make, as I tried many different things, and the main problem is
If we take in input it gets stored in al which is 8 bit thus I can't transfer it to ax, So, i made 2 more variable 1 with 8bit d2 and another with 16 bit d1 so i transferred from al to d2 and from d2 to d1.... But am still getting error.....

Comment: Umm.... Just curious, but ml.exe and link.exe comes with Dosbox ? Just asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks okay. Your screenshot shows you have only assembled and linked the code but not actually run it. To run it type:

```
pro.exe
```